# Why can't I assign struct member values to a string variable like this?

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct car {
    char make[10];
    char model[25];
    char type[10];
};

void main()
{
    struct car myCar;
    strcpy(myCar.make, "Nissan");
    strcpy(myCar.model, "Rogue");
    strcpy(myCar.type, "SUV");
    
    //char make[] = myCar.make;
    //char model[] = myCar.model;
    //char type[] = myCar.type;
}
```

I was trying to assign the value of myCar.make to make[]. Why can't I just assign the value of myCar.make to make[]?

Note: I mainly program in java, so is this problem related to my understanding of java?

Comment: `char make[] = myCar.make` is an attempt to initialize an array with a pointer - even though it looks like attempting to initialize an array with an array.

Comment: The issue is with your perception that there is such a thing as a "string variable". What you have is a char array, and arrays in C are not "first class" data types.  Why I wonder would you choose to use C rather than C++ as the more obvious route for a Java developer.  C++ has a standard library with a `string` class that you can assign.

Comment: I'd like to get into embedded systems, and I heard I should learn C then C++. Hence, the  reason as to why I chose C.

Answer (score 1):

Consider another case that also doesn't work:

```c
void foo() {
    char src[6] = "hello";
    char dst[] = src;
}
```

The situation here is identical to your code above, but simpler.

I agree, this *should* work.  The compiler *should* be able to figure out that `src` has size 6 (don't forget the null-terminator).  So `dst` *should* have size 6, and assignment should copy character by character.

However, it doesn't.  You asked *why*.  The answer is basically that, when C was invented, the standard for compilers was a lot lower so, apart from a few special cases (like when you define `src` in the first place), the language flat out doesn't work this way.  I acknowledge that may not be satisfying.

When you write the above code, the compiler basically sees:

```c
char* src = /* ??? */;
char dst[] = src;
```

This phenomenon is called 'pointer decay', and the more familiar case is for function arguments.  Hopefully it's clear why copying a pointer into an array doesn't work: `dst` is allocated on the stack.  How does the compiler know how much stack space to allocate ahead of time?  It cannot; it would have to wait until runtime to see what size string `src` points to, by which time it's too late.

Modern compilers are better, and they are aware of the problem:

```
<source>(3): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'char []' to 'char []'
<source>(3): note: There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays
```

In short, it understands that `src` is an array, but the language rules set down in the '60s and '70s don't let it infer the size.

---

Another way to look at this is that the language is not smart enough to understand more complex assignment.  Assigning character by character (the guts of `strcpy`) is actually a nontrivial operation.  The rule in C is that you can only copy things of known sizes—stuff like `int`s, pointers, and `struct`s.  An array's size is not part of its type, in C, so one array and another array have different sizes and can't be assigned.

---

I'm qualifying all of this with, "in C" because C has remained very similar to the historical original language.  Some people see this simplicity as venerable and desirable.  Others see it as pointlessly restrictive—a lack of expressivity that serves no point.

C++, inherits the rules of C, but also provides `std::string`, which understands `operator=` (and actually in this case a constructor) enough to copy:

```cpp
#include <string>
void foo() {
    char src[6] = "hello";
    std::string dst = src; //Totally fine
}
```

The compiler is still seeing `src` as a pointer by the time you get to the definition of `dst`, but `std::string` has a constructor that understands pointers, and will do the right thing: discovering the length of the pointed-to character buffer with `strlen`, allocating new memory dynamically to hold it, and copying it over character by character.

Arrays also can be defined for which the size *is* part of the type:

```cpp
#include <array>
void foo() {
    std::array<char,6> src = /* ... */;
    std::array<char,6> dst = src; //Totally fine
}
```

Of course, now for the same reason, we can't initialize `src` with `"hello"` . . .

Answer (score 1):

> I was trying to assign the value of myCar.make to make[]. Why can't I just assign the value of myCar.make to make[]?

```
char make[] = myCar.make;
```

This is better called an *initialization* than an *assignment*.  Although there are similarities, C has different rules for *initialization* and *assignment*.  An initialization occurs when an object is *defined* **and** given a value.

Unfortunately in this case, the *array* `myCar.make` is first converted to type and address of its first element, so code is like:

```
char make[] = &(myCar.make[0]);
```

That is attempting to initialize an array with a pointer - which does not make sense.

C does not offer a way to initialize an array (and determine its size) with a simple initialization.

An alternative is to define the new array with or without initializing, then *assigned* the array elements.

```
#define ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT(a)  (sizeof (a)/sizeof (a)[0])
char make[ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT(myCar.make)];

// Note : elements after the null character remain uninitialized.
strcpy(make, myCar.make);
```

---

A more C idiomatic approach involves string management.  That is perhaps more advanced that OP is ready for now.

```
struct car {
  char *make;
  char *model;
  ...
};

int main(void) {
  struct car myCar;
  strcpy(myCar.make, "Nissan");
  strcpy(myCar.model, "Rogue");

  char *make = strdup(myCar.make);
  ...
  free(make);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful! I thought arrays and pointers were interchangeable since the array name is basically a pointer to its first element and got confused because of that.

Comment: @nameless___ Remember that an array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

In C you cannot directly initialize one array with another like how you would with regular variables, because arrays are not directly assignable or initializable types in C.

Initialization occurs at the time of declaration, while assignment occurs after a variable has been declared.

When you declare an array like char make[], the compiler needs to know the size of the array at compile-time so it can allocate the right amount of memory.

When you try to do char make[] = myCar.make; you're essentially trying to initialize the array with a pointer.

The right side of the assignment (myCar.make) is an expression and has no memory allocation associated with it.

You have to copy the array element by element, which can be done using a function like strcpy().

Here's how you could modify your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct car {
    char make[10];
    char model[25];
    char type[10];
};

int main()
{
    struct car myCar;
    strcpy(myCar.make, "Nissan");
    strcpy(myCar.model, "Rogue");
    strcpy(myCar.type, "SUV");
    
    char make[10];
    char model[25];
    char type[10];
    
    strcpy(make, myCar.make);
    strcpy(model, myCar.model);
    strcpy(type, myCar.type);
    
    printf("Make: %s\n", make);
    printf("Model: %s\n", model);
    printf("Type: %s\n", type);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, new strings are declared for make, model, and type with the same sizes as the strings in the car struct.

Then strcpy() is used to copy the contents of myCar.make, myCar.model, and myCar.type to make, model, and type.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are correct (I edited the first two sentences of the answer for some clarification). The statement is an attempt to initialize make with the value of myCar.make, not to assign myCar.make to make after it has been defined.

Answer (score -2):

You're trying to declare new character arrays and assign them the value of myCar.make, myCar.model, and myCar.type, right? But here's the catch: In C , arrays (including those storing strings, aka character arrays) are a bit trickier than simple data types. They don't play nice with the assignment operator (=).

So, when you say char make[] = myCar.make;, what the C compiler hears is "Hey, create a new array and copy the content of myCar.make into it!" But the compiler's like "Uh , no can do, mate. I'm not built to handle copying arrays just using =. Sorry!"

Instead, you gotta use something like strcpy() function , similar to what you've already done while assigning the values to myCar.make, myCar.model, and myCar.type.

```
char make[10];
char model[25];
char type[10];

strcpy(make , myCar.make);
strcpy(model , myCar.model);
strcpy(type , myCar.type);
```

You declare make , model, and type as character arrays with an appropriate size (same as in your struct), and then you copy the content of the corresponding struct members into them.

My computer is not beside me, I can not check my code, it is really a long time that I didn't program with C.

Comment: Then why can you do this: char make[] = "Nissan";

Comment: ...I didn't do this , buddy

Comment: @nameless___ -- you can do `char make[] = "Nissan";` because string literals can be used as array initializers in C. You can't do `char brand[] = "Nissan"; char make[] = brand;` because `brand` is an array and arrays decay to pointers in most expressions in C; a pointer is not a valid initializer for an array.